# How can I identify which text within a page is "too small to read" as reported by Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, fonts, mobile-friendly-tool

Google Search Console intermittently claims that I have "Text too small to read" and gives just URL to my page.

How can I get more specific location of supposed problem?

[image]

It is a bit more specific version of [How to resolve "Text too small to read" error from Google Search Console's mobile usability report?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/127891/how-to-resolve-text-too-small-to-read-error-from-google-search-consoles-mobil) - I am fine also with discovering what is triggering this and discovering that it is a false positive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you run a [Lighthouse Audit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse#devtools) in Chrome, under the "Document doesn't use legible font sizes" report it will show you the [exact CSS selector that is causing the small text issue, and the source of the offending CSS](https://web.dev/font-size/).

Comment: I guess that given that both are made by Google it is likely that checks are matching or at least similar, and getting something better is unlikely.

Comment: Use responsive Galaxy S5 layout to run Lighthouse and identify your "Text too small"

Answer (score 3):

The intermittency could simply be caused by field data of a few users who's browser portal is small or by periodic changes to Google's algorithm.

Have you looked at the page using your browser's developer tools and various window sizes?  I've found that if I try the various portal sizes, I can usually spot the problem.  When I look at your page with the portal set for an iPhone 11, the map is incredibly small.